# Why is stage ignoring the new defined positions when restoring window?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm doing some tests with jfx gui framework, so i needed to make my own custom window. In meantime, i managed to find helpful resource for my research in deceased [jfx 2 samples](https://github.com/lusalome/javafx-ensemble/blob/master/src/main/java/ensemble/controls/WindowButtons.java), but the problem that arises is the fact my stage doesn't return (restore) to defined (original) position if maximized:

```
package MyStage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

/**
 *
 * @author author
 */
public class MaxTest extends Application{
    private Stage stage;
private boolean maximized = false;
private Rectangle2D backupWindowBounds = null;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        Button btnmax = new Button("Max/Res");
        Button btnExit = new Button("Exit");
        HBox root = new HBox(btnmax, btnExit);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,350,200);
        btnmax.setOnAction(e->this.toogleMaximized());
        btnExit.setOnAction(e->stage.hide());
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        stage.setScene(scene);
                this.stage=stage;
        stage.show();
    }
    public void toogleMaximized() {        
        final Screen screen = Screen.getScreensForRectangle(stage.getX(), stage.getY(), 1, 1).get(0);
        if (maximized) {
            maximized = false;
            if (backupWindowBounds != null) {
                stage.setX(backupWindowBounds.getMinX());
                stage.setY(backupWindowBounds.getMinY());
                stage.setWidth(backupWindowBounds.getWidth());
                stage.setHeight(backupWindowBounds.getHeight());
                ResizeHelper.ResizeHandler.BORDER=10;
            }
        } else {
            maximized = true;
            backupWindowBounds = new Rectangle2D(stage.getX(), stage.getY(), stage.getWidth(), stage.getHeight());
            stage.setX(screen.getVisualBounds().getMinX());
            stage.setY(screen.getVisualBounds().getMinY());
            stage.setWidth(screen.getVisualBounds().getWidth());
            stage.setHeight(screen.getVisualBounds().getHeight());
                            ResizeHelper.ResizeHandler.BORDER=0;
        }
    }
}
```

ResizeHelper:

```
package MyStage;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author author
 */
public abstract class ResizeHelper {
    ResizeHandler resizeHandler;
     /**
     * Handler to process the resizing of the the given stage.
     */
    static class ResizeHandler implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {

        /** Space to consider around the stage border for resizing */
        static  int BORDER = 10;

        /** Stage to which the handler is implemented */
        static Stage stage;

        /** Current cursor reference to the scene */
        private Cursor cursor = Cursor.DEFAULT;

        /** X position of the drag start */
        private double startX = 0;

        /** Y position of the drag start */
        private double startY = 0;

        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @param stageTmp Stage to which resizing to be set.
         */
        public ResizeHandler(final Stage stageTmp) {
            stage = stageTmp;
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(final MouseEvent event) {
            final EventType<? extends MouseEvent> eventType = event.getEventType();
            final Scene scene = stage.getScene();
            final double mouseEventX = event.getSceneX();
            final double mouseEventY = event.getSceneY();
            final double sceneWidth = scene.getWidth();
            final double sceneHeight = scene.getHeight();

            if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED.equals(eventType)) {
                setCursor(mouseEventX, mouseEventY, sceneWidth, sceneHeight);
                scene.setCursor(cursor);

            } else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED.equals(eventType)) {
                startX = stage.getWidth() - mouseEventX;
                startY = stage.getHeight() - mouseEventY;
                consumeEventIfNotDefaultCursor(event);

            } else if (MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED.equals(eventType) && !Cursor.DEFAULT.equals(cursor)) {
                consumeEventIfNotDefaultCursor(event);
                if (!Cursor.W_RESIZE.equals(cursor) && !Cursor.E_RESIZE.equals(cursor)) {
                    processVerticalDrag(event);
                }

                if (!Cursor.N_RESIZE.equals(cursor) && !Cursor.S_RESIZE.equals(cursor)) {
                    processHorizontalDrag(event);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Consumes the mouse event if the cursor is not the DEFAULT cursor.
         *
         * @param event MouseEvent instance.
         */
        private void consumeEventIfNotDefaultCursor(final MouseEvent event) {
            if (!cursor.equals(Cursor.DEFAULT)) {
                event.consume();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Processes the horizontal drag movement and resizes the window width.
         *
         * @param event MouseEvent instance.
         */
        private void processHorizontalDrag(final MouseEvent event) {
            final double minWidth =
                    stage.getMinWidth() > BORDER * 2 ? stage.getMinWidth() : BORDER * 2;
            final double mouseEventX = event.getSceneX();
            if (Cursor.NW_RESIZE.equals(cursor)
                || Cursor.W_RESIZE.equals(cursor)
                || Cursor.SW_RESIZE.equals(cursor)) {
                if (stage.getWidth() > minWidth || mouseEventX < 0) {
                    stage.setWidth(stage.getX() - event.getScreenX() + stage.getWidth());
                    stage.setX(event.getScreenX());
                }
            } else if (stage.getWidth() > minWidth || mouseEventX + startX - stage.getWidth() > 0) {
                stage.setWidth(mouseEventX + startX);
                System.out.println(stage.getWidth());
            }
        }

        /**
         * Processes the vertical drag movement and resizes the window height.
         *
         * @param event MouseEvent instance.
         */
        private void processVerticalDrag(final MouseEvent event) {
            final double minHeight =
                    stage.getMinHeight() > BORDER * 2 ? stage.getMinHeight() : BORDER * 2;
            final double mouseEventY = event.getSceneY();
            if (Cursor.NW_RESIZE.equals(cursor)
                || Cursor.N_RESIZE.equals(cursor)
                || Cursor.NE_RESIZE.equals(cursor)) {
                if (stage.getHeight() > minHeight || mouseEventY < 0) {
                    stage.setHeight(stage.getY() - event.getScreenY() + stage.getHeight());
                    stage.setY(event.getScreenY());
                }
            } else if (stage.getHeight() > minHeight || mouseEventY + startY - stage.getHeight() > 0) {
                stage.setHeight(mouseEventY + startY);
                System.out.println(stage.getHeight());
            }
        }

        /**
         * Determines and sets the appropriate cursor based on the mouse position in relative to scene bounds.
         *
         * @param mouseEventX X position of mouse in the scene.
         * @param mouseEventY Y position of mouse in the scene.
         * @param sceneWidth Width of the scene.
         * @param sceneHeight Height of the scene.
         */
        private void setCursor(final double mouseEventX, final double mouseEventY, final double sceneWidth,
                final double sceneHeight) {
            final Cursor cursor1;
            if (mouseEventX < BORDER && mouseEventY < BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.NW_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX < BORDER && mouseEventY > sceneHeight - BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.SW_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX > sceneWidth - BORDER && mouseEventY < BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.NE_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX > sceneWidth - BORDER && mouseEventY > sceneHeight - BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.SE_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX < BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.W_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventX > sceneWidth - BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.E_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventY < BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.N_RESIZE;
            } else if (mouseEventY > sceneHeight - BORDER) {
                cursor1 = Cursor.S_RESIZE;
            } else {
                cursor1 = Cursor.DEFAULT;
            }
            cursor = cursor1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     */
    private ResizeHelper() {

    }

    /**
     * Adds the resize handler to the provided stage.
     *
     * @param stage Stage to which the resizing should be implemented.
     */
    public static void addResizeHandler(final Stage stage) {
        ResizeHandler resizeHandler = new ResizeHandler(stage);
        //stage.setMinHeight(stage.getHeight());
        //stage.setMinWidth(stage.getWidth());
        //stage.setMaxHeight(stage.getMaxHeight());
        //stage.setMaxWidth(stage.getMaxWidth());
        stage.getScene().addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, resizeHandler);
    }
}
```

Please help! I only want to my window restore to defined (original) position in method `toogleMaximized()`, what doesn't happen. I even tried manual positions for `stage.setY` and `stage.setX`, but nothing works and it's stuck in upper right side...

Comment: What a strange thing... I cannot see why the stage is rejecting new repositioning in restore state. Maybe it's the reason why Oracle removed custom title bar in Ensemble8? I'll try reconsider a different approach in case it's messed up anyway...

Comment: The Ensemble2.2 snippet will "save" the stage width and height, but will always loose the last x and y coordinates of screen after exiting maximize window state... BTW, the snippet isn't [reliable](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Screen.html) (What i doubt)... Or it might be a defect related to [stage](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#xProperty())... Tried others approaches to no avail. The stage looses the correct position because it may truly refuse to recompute new repositioning or location.

Comment: I think that happens because the setters and getters methods were declared final (didn't pay attention to that...) they're some kind of "interesting" constants, since Java doesn't have built-in support we could in some cases call 'em that. Maybe the only way out is override those methods in a class which extends stage's window... Maybe in the end it's not worth it, I'm trying to find a way to "emulate" OS's decoration and embellish the windows bar like Telegram in Linux and keep windows behaviors. JetBrains's custom window with swing flatlaf is cool too.